# Aggregate method in mongodb not working in java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
        //unwind
        DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$organization");

     // run aggregation
        AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(unwind);
```

In this code I am getting:

> The method aggregate(DBObject) is undefined for the type DBCollection

Note: I am using mongo-java-driver-2.9.0.jar and com.mongodb-2.5.2.jar

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: I am not sure whether you have resolved the issue. I don't have the relevant Mongo version mentioned in your question. I have the solution written on Mongo version 3.2. Please let me know if you need it. I will share the answer.